# namespace "std" has no member "clamp"

Tags: c++, std

VS2015 wont compile my code, says namespace "std" has no member "clamp", although intellisense picks it up just fine and tells me the parameters and return value.
Yes, i have included the header.

```
#include <Math/Matrix3D.h>
#include <glm.hpp>
#include <gtx/transform.hpp>
#include <Utils/Clock.h>

#include <algorithm>

void somefunc()
{
viewPos.y = std::clamp(viewPos.y, -0.95f, 0.95f);
}
```

Comment: `std::clamp` looks to be C++17 exclusive. Do you have your compiler flags set to compile C++17?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 [claims little support for C++17 features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx), I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't have `std::clamp` even if you asked for C++17 support.

Comment: You might want to check and see if there is an experimental version of the header.

Comment: Clamp is [supported](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c17-features-and-stl-fixes-in-vs-2017-15-3/) since VS2015.3

Comment: Having the same issue right now. It's so weird...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would have to use the `/std:c++latest` switch to enable C++17 additions to the standard.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/06/07/standards-version-switches-in-the-compiler/

Comment: For VSCode, assuming the Microsoft C/C++ Extension is installed, and basic system header files are set in the Include Path setting of the extension, go to the C/C++ Configurations page in Settings and select c++17 as the C++ standard.

Comment: I have set my C++ Language Standard to `latest`, `/std:c++2017`, and `/std:c++2020`, and it still doesn't find it.

Comment: @ajpieri I had a same problem in visual studio. Switching from x86 to x64 fixed it.